# The v-model in the view is not updated until after reloading the page for the first time

Tags: vue.js, v-model

Because when updating the value of a variable in the method, it is not updated in the v-model of the view ?.

If I reload the page the `method v-on: change ="reCalcTotal(index, art.stock_solicited)"` works correctly, and updates the subtotal value every time `"art.stock_solicited"` changes.

But until I reload the page for the first time, the method does not modify the v-model in the view.

What alternative do I have to solve it?

`HTML`

```html
    <tr v-for="(art, index) in arGeneratedOrders" v-if="art.stock_solicited > 0">
        <td>
            $@{{ art.subtotal.toFixed(1) }}
            <input type="text" v-model="art.subtotal">
         </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" v-model="art.stock_solicited" v-on:change="reCalcTotal(index, art.stock_solicited)">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
          Total: $@{{total.toFixed(2)}}
        </td>
    </tr>
```

`js`

```js
    data: {
        arGeneratedOrders:''
    },
    computed: {
        total(){
            let total=0;
            this.arGeneratedOrders.forEach(item => {
                total +=  item.subtotal;
            });
            return total
        }
    },
    methods: {
        reCalcTotal: function(index, newStockSolicited) {
            this.arGeneratedOrders[index].stock_solicited=newStockSolicited;
            this.arGeneratedOrders[index].subtotal=(this.arGeneratedOrders[index].stock_solicited)*this.arGeneratedOrders[index].purchase_price,
            localStorage.setItem('lsGeneratedOrders', JSON.stringify(this.arGeneratedOrders));
            this.total;
            alert('Index:'+index+' - New:'+newStockSolicited+' - ='+this.arGeneratedOrders[index].subtotal); //This alert shows the updated variables, but the values do not change in the view.
        }
}
```

Comment: try to add `key` in <tr> like `<tr v-for="(art, index) in arGeneratedOrders" v-if="art.stock_solicited > 0" :key="index">`

Comment: I tried. But still not updated in the view

Comment: You should initialize `arGeneratedOrders` as Array instead of String. And because of the issues with Array changes tracking by Vue observers - you should NEVER directly assign values to an Array member. Instead you should either `Array.push()` or `Array.splice()` - otherwise the Vue's reactivity system will not work. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection

Comment: As @IVOGELOV said. This is the solution. Initialize:
let resData [].
  And then I assign the array to a new array
this.arGeneratedOrders = resData;
This makes vue change tracking work correctly.

Comment: `code
     let resData = [];
     resData = response.data;
                for (let i=0; i < resData.length; i++) {
                    resData[i].note_state = false;
                    resData[i].note_text = '';
                    resData[i].classOptionIcons = '';
                }
                this.arGeneratedOrders = resData;
                localStorage.setItem('lsGeneratedOrders', JSON.stringify(this.arGeneratedOrders));
`